# Total derivative without specified function

Tags: derivatives

How to take total derivative if I don't have a function?

For example
$$ u=f(t),\ \ when \ \ t = x+y $$

I assume that it's something like
$$ du = \frac{∂u}{∂t}*dt $$
but how do we use information about t value?

Comment: You have to take the derivative with respect to some variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivative of f should be known, say g:
$$ du = \frac{d f(t)}{dt} (dx + dy) =g(t)(dx + dy)=g(x+y)(dx + dy) $$